# Doubleclick on iOS or any touch device

Tags: jquery, touch

I have a website where the links have two different behaviors: on one click I filter the contents, on double click the user can actually follow the link.

It's implemented using jQuery and works fine in a browser, but once I try to use it from a mobile device (e.g. iOS) it doesn't work.

Here is the code I use below, can anybody help, please? I guess it happens because of the conflict between touch and double click... Maybe I could use a different jQuery directive? Or maybe there's a library to deal with this sort of thing you could recommend?

```
$(".app-context-link").on('dblclick', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   window.location = e.target.href;
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could give [this](https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Mobile-Events) plugin a try

Comment: Great! Any idea how to do this without the plugin? Thanks!

Comment: You could see their implementation and use only the parts that you need, any reason not to use the plugin?

Comment: Just want to have as few dependencies as possible, that's all... I'll give it a try though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:
Sorry, for some reason I misread this (I was searching through Android tags). In that case the functionality of onClick(View v) would be placed inside of your click functionality. If I am not mistaken (not much js background sorry) it would look something like:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    // perform functionality
});
```

--Original Post--

You can create a variable, something like long firstClick = -1 to determine the first click. Then another variable like final int MAX_TIME_BETWEEN_CLICKS = 1000; Then do something like this

```
onClick(View v){
    if(firstClick = -1){
          firstClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    else if(System.currentTimeMills() - firstClick < MAX_TIME_BETWEEN_CLICKS){
           // Double Click
           firstClick = -1;
    }
}
```

May not be the best way, but off of the top of my head it is a rigged way that should work.

Comment: Thanks! But should I put it inside my $().on function?